# Android: get all the notifications by code

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am using some home replacement that allow me to hide the notification Bar and that's something I really like.

All the informations can be replaced by some widgets, but I would like to display the notifications too.

As I already developed some applications, I would like to know if there is a command line that allow an application to get all the notifications. I plan to add this to a widget or a toast.

Thank a lot for any clue or help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Android API Level 18 (Android 4.3) there is a class **NotificationListenerService**.
You must set the Permission **BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE** and use a intent-filter with the action **NotificationListenerService**.

```
 <service android:name=".NotificationListener"
          android:label="@string/service_name"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Source: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications%28%29)

Answer (score 9):

I will answer my question because I found something on an other forum.

Seem that you can access them declaring your application as an (sorry for the french term, I couldn't find an english translation) "gestionnaire d'accessibilité" that you may translate as "accessibility manager"

More information here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html

That may be dangerous and has a lot of negative point, but an other dev that is also working on a custom Home assure me that this feature work and he was able to create his own notification bar.

Comment: could you give the link to the forum where you find this? I still don't quite understand how this work. Thanks.

Comment: as far as i understand, this is limited by the fact that accessibility must be enabled, as well as this specific accessibility service, right?