# Geting the list of notifications in the status bar?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, statusbar

How can I get the list of the titles of the active notification messages, including notifications my app did not create, in the status bar?

If this isn't possible, how can I get titles from just the notifications my app created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030626/android-get-all-the-notifications-by-code