# How can I intercept the updates/notifications from an app in Android / iOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone

Supposed I want to know what were the notifications provided by a particular app between time X and time Y (it could be even the simple sms app) on Android/iOS, is it possible?

Are there any specific apps that allow/do not allow us to intercept these notifications?

Comment: Definitely not possible on iOS, and most probably not on Android. That would be quite a security flaw if it were possible.

Comment: This is how Pushbullet works so it is not impossible on Android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: get all the notifications by code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030626/android-get-all-the-notifications-by-code)

Answer (score 1):

On iOS you can get access to 3rd party notifications from a second device that presents itself to the iOS device as a Bluetooth accessory.  That's how Pushbullet gets notifications to the desktop.  See:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html