# How does Pushbullet for iOS manage to access and show all of iOS notifications on other devices?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, push

The new version of Pushbullet app (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pushbullet/id810352052?mt=8) for iOS and Mac can show you all the notifications you get on your phone inside their Mac app.
Not just the notifications going to the app itself - all notifications from all applications.
How did they manage to do that? I can't figure out which APIs they are using to do this.

Comment: Seems it's possible with Bluetooth:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28177349/1472887

Answer (score 0):

In General, Apple device gives the access to Notification to BLE, so that Notifications can be shown on any onboard system like Car's Dashboard. So I think they are using ani API related to that.

This might be helpful
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html