# How to acces and get a list of the user's notifcations

Tags: android, android-listview, notifications, push-notification

I want to create a android launcher but I want to work as a full screen app like the homepage
I want to have a custom status bar that when you swipe you can get all the users notification in a custom display design
The question here is how can I get all the notifications that the user got

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: get all the notifications by code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030626/android-get-all-the-notifications-by-code)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on API 18+, this will do

> A service that receives calls from the system when new notifications
>   are posted or removed, or their ranking changed.
>
> To extend this class, you must declare the service in your manifest
>   file with the BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE permission and
>   include an intent filter with the SERVICE_INTERFACE action.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

[NotificationListenerService Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926236/notificationlistenerservice-implementation)